# Scrapy SgmlLinkExtractor how to scrape li tags with changing id's

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

How can I get an element at this specific location:

[Check picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CkzTH.png)

The XPath is:

```
//*[@id="id316"]/span[2]
```

I got this path from google chrome browser. I basically want to retreive the number at this specific location with the following statement:

`zimmer = response.xpath('//*[@id="id316"]/span[2]').extract()`

However I'm not getting anything but an empty string. I found out that the id value is different for each element in the list I'm interested in. Is there a way to write this expression such that it works for generic numbers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the corresponding label and get the [following sibling](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Axes/following-sibling) element containing the value:

```
//span[. = 'Zimmer']/following-sibling::span/text()
```

And, note the bonus to the readability of the locator.